# Could not record any guest kernel reference relocation symbols using Intel Processor Trace (Intel PT)

Tags: intel, trace, processor, kvm, perf

We have set up one VM (Virtual Machine) (Ubuntu Desktop 16.04) on VMM (virtual-manager) running QEMU / KVM. We are using Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 as our HOST OS. We execute suspicious C language code on our guest VM. We want to intercept certain instructions executed in the form of suspicious C language code on our guest VM from our HOST OS.

To accomplish this task, We are trying to capture Intel PT traces for our guest OS using the below command on our host. We're getting the following error when running this command on our terminal.

`$ perf kvm --guest --guestkallsyms=guest-kallsyms --guestmodules=guest-modules record -e intel_pt//`

`Couldn't record guest kernel [0]'s reference relocation symbol.`

" `guest-kallsyms` and `guest-modules` are the `kallsyms` and `module` files we copied from the `guest` onto our `host`. "

Does `perf kvm` command support `intel_pt//`?

Our System Configuration:

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-66-generic
Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: Hi Darshan, please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982315/ - Arnabjyoti Kalita says that he was unable to use intel-pt with Broadwell CPU, and it might be possible with Skylake and newer. What is your exact CPU model?

Comment: Hi osgx, Thanks for your concern and response. I'm using Intel Core i5-8265U 8th Gen - Microarchitecture / CPU Family - " Whiskey Lake "

Comment: Let me add some more details. Plz see the link for the output of tool for querying VMX capabilities on my laptop. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KgOS1nYjCdiJd5DAowhhz3qnDuLkxmgI/view?usp=sharing